# Filestyle Bootstrap on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to write this HTML code in my .html.erb :

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-icon="false" data-classButton="btn btn-default" data-classInput="form-control inline input-s">
```

But,I don't know how I should to write the *data* codes..

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class:'filestyle'     %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's like any other attribute:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class:'filestyle', 'data-icon' => false, 'data-classButton' => 'btn-default', 'data-classInput' => 'form-control inline input-s' %>
```